# Android: onClick event listener doesn't work on linearlayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to implement an onclick for the entire layout but it won't work.

Here is my function for my RelativeLayout:

```
public void updateRange(View v)
{
    System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

and here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:id="@+id/xasdf"
    android:onClick="updateRange">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toptab"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.333333"
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:background="#fffdb64b" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Solutions"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.333333"
            android:id="@+id/solutionsButton"
            android:background="#fffdb64b" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mode"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.333333"
            android:id="@+id/modeButton"
            android:background="#fffdb64b" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chartlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toptab"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:hint="y = ..." />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Graph"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0"
            android:onClick="drawGraph" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Table"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="#ffd0d0d0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the extra line below to your `Relative Layout` description:

```
...
android:onClick="updateRange"
android:clickable="true">
```

Comment: @Henry Yeah it does. I just tested it on one of my fairly complicated Relative Layouts. You must have some other issue then.